# What am I doing wrong in my controller that's causing the 500 error?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, debugging, axios

I can't understand what on earth I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to send the URL of the file uploaded by the user into my DB via an `axios` POST request but but I'm getting a 500 error.

Note: I'm using React.js for frontend.

According to the error in my network calls (it's showing the same error in Laravl logs), the `PostPicturesController`'s the issue but I can't wrap my head around why `$postPictures` is the culprit.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's `PostPicturesController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\PostPictures;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostPicturesController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, PostPictures $postPicture) {
        $uploadPic = $postPicture->user()->postPictures->create([
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);

        return response()->json($uploadPic->with('user')->find($uploadPic->id));
    }
}
```

Here's `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function postPictures() {
        return $this->hasMany(PostPictures::class);
    }
}
```

Here's the `axios` call:

```
submitImageAndRedirect() {
    let picUrl = this.state.previewImgURL;
    axios.post('/home', {
        body: picUrl
    }).then(response => {
        // console
        console.log(response);
        // set state
        this.setState({
            pictures: [picUrl, response.data]
        });
    });
}
```

Here are my routes in `web.php`:

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', "HomeController@index")->name('home');
    Route::get('/home', "HomeController@index")->name('home');
    Route::post('/home', 'PostPicturesController@create')->name('home');
});
```

error inside my network calls:

```
{message: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$postPictures",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/Users/name/workstation/website/app/Http/Controllers/PostPicturesController.php"
line: 12
message: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$postPictures"
```

Comment: `$postPicture->user()->postPictures` to `$postPicture->user->postPictures` make sure `PostPictures` should related with `user`.    `user` related `postPictures`

Comment: you are using **API** calls you need to pass an `token` to grant your request.

Comment: @Laravel just posted my User.php file

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
 public function create(Request $request, PostPictures $postPicture) { ... }
```

You are trying to inject a **PostPictures** model via the route.  But you haven't bound the incoming model to that route.

You can do this using a variable on your route something like this:

```
Route::post('/home/{postPicture}', 'PostPicturesController@create')->name('home');
```

where the route variable matches the injected variable on the controller exactly.

But, if you are sending the ID directly via a data object, it may be easier to just load the `$request` variable, and then pull the `id`, and subsequently the model with that id, within your method.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure either of these will work as you wish.  I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with this create method.  If you are trying to create a new PostPictures model - then what is Laravel supposed to be injecting?  IE if there is no model yet, how can you pull one from the database?  By convention, usually this method doesn't have an `id` coming in, but you would show a form or something to create a new model here and store it in the `store` method.  As you have it, it looks like a bit of a loop (postpicture -> user -> postpicture).

Bottom line though is that the error is likely happening because there is nothing sent to that method to allow the model to be injected - no id = no `$postPicture`

If you are just trying to create a new model and give the right user to it, you can simplify your method a bit.  Something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $uID = \Auth::user()->id;
    $uploadPic = PostPicture::create([
        'body' => $request->get('body')
        'user_id' => $uID    // assuming user_id is the fk
    ]);

    // If you want to load the user on the new object:
    $uploadPic->load('user');
```

Comment: `But, if you are sending the ID directly via a data object, it may be easier to just load the $request variable, and then pull the id, and subsequently the model with that id, within your method.`.  Yes, that's what I want to do, are there any examples out there that demonstrate this?

Comment: What `id` are you looking to send to your method though? If this is a brand new PostPicture there is no `id` to send from your blade page, right? Or are you looking to attach the newly created postPicture to a user?   See Edit :)